# Hero Animation for Network Image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to add Hero animation for a Network Image. 
The problem is, when I navigate from one screen to another the image loads again on second screen and so I am not able to see the animation.

After loading complete, if I repeat this navigation (from 1st screen to 2nd) this is working fine.

So the question is, How can I achieve this animation when I navigate for first time?

Error-Output:
[Click Here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/63658662/208286442-41bd8301-363e-48ec-a057-26c0809b8f1d.mp4)

Code:
FirstScreen.dart

```
Hero(
  tag: 'tag',
  child: Image.network(
    'https://...',
    cacheHeight: 1080,
    cacheWidth: 1080,
    fit: BoxFit.none,
    scale: 5,
  ),
),
```

secondScreen.dart

```
Hero(
  tag: 'tag',
  child: Image.network(
    'https://...',
  ),
)
```

With **CachedNetworkImage**:
firstScreen.dart

```
Hero(
  tag: tag
  child: CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: 'url',
    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
    memCacheHeight: 1080,
    memCacheWidth: 1080,
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset('assets/..'),
  ),
)
```

secondScreen.dart

```
Hero(
  tag: tag,
  child: CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: 'url',
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset('assets/...'),
  ),
),
```

Comment: is the same behaior happens if you remove cacheWidth cacheHeight, scale, fit properties ?

Comment: and is your image source path variable, I mean is something like this: https://source.unsplash.com/random/2 ?

Comment: yes, even if I remove cacheWidth-height I have the same issue. and my source path is from API.

Comment: okay, so you have also a constant path not like what I mentioned, are you using this tag anywhere else than those two ?

Comment: However, try make that widget in a custom one, then use the same constructor of the widget in both screens

Comment: Use cached_network_image plugin to load images as it'll cache images, without reloading SAme image.

Comment: @Gwhyyy Yes, I have api data in my model class and accessing this image from there. and in my entire project I have only 2 hero tags.

Can you elaborate what is mean my custom widget? I don't understand it.

Comment: @OMiShah I tried CachedNetworkImage() but I am not aware if this package allow us to define the cached image? 
I mean to say like hero widget have tag which helps widget to relocate the content with animation likewise does CachedNetworkImage have any key so that we can provide key and it gives us the cachedImage

Comment: @ravipatel0508, no, but if you pass the same image url and if cached version of the URL image exist then it'll return the cached version else load from the network.

Comment: @OMiShah I am passing the same image on ChachedNetworkImage but still it takes little long time to load the image.
do you know any solution for this?

Comment: @ravipatel0508, add your updated code after using CachedNetworkImage. You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @OMiShah I edited the question, you can check the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

create loading builder in the network image widget and use a placeholder instead of image when the image is not fully loaded something like this

```
Image.network(
                            imagePath,
                            // width: 100,
                            // height: 100,
                            loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                Widget child,
                                ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                              if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                              return Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: // PlaceHolderWidget()
                                  ),
                              );
                            },
                            // fit: BoxFit.none,
                          )
```

Comment: I tried adding placeholder still I am not getting the animation

Comment: can you share the result

Comment: There is no change in result. I mentioned a link in question you can check it there.